# how to hide components on click of router link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-component

I have my `app.js` in that `App.js` I want to show some components when clicked on that router.
Here is my `App.js` code

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Header'
import Slider from './Slider';
import Section from './Section';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Register from './Register';
class IndecisionApp extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="wrapper"> 

                    <Header/>
                    <Route path="/register" component={Register}></Route>
                    <Slider />
                    <Section /> 
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default IndecisionApp;\
```

I want to hide `Section` and `Slider` components when I click on Router.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing react-router wrong.

The correct way is this

```
  <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="wrapper"> 
          <Header/>
         <Switch>
          <Route path="/register" component={Register}></Route>

        </Switch>
          <Slider />
          <Section /> 
          <Footer />
      </div>
   </BrowserRouter>
```

more on react router
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: it is working fine but not showing slider when i remove `topics` from it does not show section also

Comment: when you visit the url  `localhost:3000/topics ` then only slider component will show

Comment: i don't want it to be like this. i want everything should show on index except register and when i click on `register` then the full registration page should show up

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have a **`home`** component and that only show as landing page including **`section`** and **`slide`**.

So there should be basically two route one is for **`landing`** another is for **`register`**, like follows

```
<Route path="/register" component={Register} />
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

But as your home/landing/index page should show section and slide together so I change the home route a little bit and finally it sum up with the following code

```
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <Header />
          <div>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
          </div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path={"/register"} component={Register} />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={() => (
                <React.Fragment>
                  <Home />
                  <Slider />
                  <Section />
                </React.Fragment>
              )}
            />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Please make me clear if your idea is something different

Comment: I have solved this issue now i have another question

Comment: Tell me your 2nd question